# JsValidation en Laravel 8 error en validar campo unico

Tags: laravel-7, postgresql-12

tengo un problema que no entiendo. Estoy usando JsValidator para hacer las validaciones de los campos de los formularios en laravel, pero cuando quiero validar que un campo no se repita como por ejemplo el correo, me lanza error 500  y me muestra el tipico mensajito chocante "woops, looks likes something went wrong'. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando reviso la consola resulta que esta saliendo peticiones post cosa q no deberia.
muestro mi validacion.
nota: la validacion esta en el controlador.

```
  protected $rule=[
           'name'=> 'required',
           'last_name'=> 'required',
           'email'=> 'required|email|unique:users,email',
           'password'=>'required',
           'confirm_password' =>'same:password|required'
          
        ];
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui llamo a la vista y le paso las reglas a seguir.

```
  public function create()
    {
        $roles = roles::get();
        $data['validator'] = JsValidator::make($this->rule,$this->messages);
        return view('usuarios.create',compact('roles'),$data);
    }
```

Comment: Estás haciendo una validación `on submit`?

Comment: Si creo que encontre la solucion, ya publico el problema

Comment: Deberías agregar el error que se grabó en el log de errores de Laravel

Answer (score 0):

Bueno amigos el problema era que no estaba colocando la validacion en el metodo store, dado que la validacion envia peticiones post que caen en dicho metodo.

solo agregue esto :

```
Validator::make($request->all(),$this->rule,$this->messages)->validate();
```

en el metodo store

Answer (score 0):

Si es directamente en el controlador puedes usar un Request en tus validaciones, en la documentacion oficial viene como hacer dicho procedimiento, ahi puedes configurar todo, desde las reglas hasta el tipo y el mesaje que puedes retormar.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation
puedes mandarlo a llamar si no es un metodo pre-determinado de esta manera

```
$validated = $request->validated();
```

O puedes hacer un switch case en el request para cada metodo (put, post, get, delete)
y que el Request valide automaticamente.